# ios parse one query many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, parse-platform

I have the following table structure:

User

```
id
email
etc
```

Conversation

```
id
```

Message

```
Id
Convo Id
User Id (the creator)
data
```

Participants

```
Convo_id 
User_id (the user who is part of the conversation)
```

My question is using [Parse.com](http://parse.com) how do I formulate a query so that I can do the following:

As user a, I want to get all of my conversations. Therefore first go through the Participants table and get each Convo_id where User_id = UserA.id

Then I have an array of Convo_id's that UserA is having. **My problem is how do I go back and get the other participants using each Convo_id from the original query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your question, the `Participants` class should actually just be an array of `User` on the `Conversation`.

If your model is built as I describe, then you can just query `Conversation` as follows:

```
query.equalTo('Participants', userA);
```

Using `equalTo()` on an array property means "array contains this value". When the value is a ParseObject it will compare the objectId and see if that is in the array.

Also, make sure you don't manually store the ID, in code you should store the Parse Object, it will then store the ID as a reference that means you can use the system better.

In the case that you actually do need to use a `Participants` class as a many-to-many join, you can use:

```
query.equalTo("user", userA);
// include the full conversation class from its link
query.include("convo");
```

The results will then be `Participants` with a `convo` property that is a full `Conversation` instance. In theory you could end up with the same conversation more than once if your data allows, it is up to you to filter out duplicates if needed.

Comment: and a quick question: are you saying that there would be a way to get all of the messages associated with a particular conversation within the same query? You lost me after query.equalTo("user", userA);

Comment: If you just wanted all messages for a single conversation, then `messageQuery.equalTo("convo", conversationObject)` assuming you switched to using references as suggested.